# How to insert nested object using stored procedure in sql

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ado.net, sql-server-2014, dapper

I am having the nested object model as follows:

```
      public class Product
        {
         public List<ProductOffering> ProductOfferings { get; set; }
        }
      public class ProductOffering
        {
            public int OfferingId { get; set; }
            public string OfferingDescription { get; set; }
            public string OfferingType { get; set; }
            public List<OfferingPriceRegion> PriceRegions { get; set; }
        }
```

I want to insert `Product` along with list of `ProductOffering` which having again list of `OfferingPriceRegion` in single stored procedure (`SPInsertProduct`)using C#. what is the best approach except entity framework. because ProductOfferings in Product may be in large number in count say 400. where entity framework may take more time in looping save functionality. Please suggest.

Comment: Without an ORM probably your best bet are [Table Value Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @red-swan If you're using SQL Server 2016, JSON might be an option, although currently TVPs or even XML are your best options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Dapper` being an `ADO.Net` based object mapper, best option would be using `TableValuedParameters`, where complete required data can send to the database in a single call.

Following are the important points:

- Dapper takes the TVP as a `DataTable`
- For `IEnumerable<T>` to `DataTable`, you can use the `System.Data.DatasetExtensions` method `CopyToDataTable` or there's an Nuget API [FastMember](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FastMember/) to achieve the same

**Few Caveats:**

- Number of Columns, columns names and their order shall be exactly same for `TVP` and the `DataTable`, else it will not work and error will not suggest the issue, this mapping is not same as Json mapping where schema mismatch isn't an issue

If the number of records are very high, you may want to divide into multiple `DataTables` and use Async-Await to do the same operation concurrently.

Comment: I'm running .NET Core which does not include DataSet/DataTable yet (and I hope it never does because it's horrible). It'd be great if there was IEnumerable<T> support directly, but I don't think there is :( Currently I'm stuck.